# Query to get PostgreSQL Database from dotnet command

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postgresql

```
        public async Task<List<AlarmStatusServiceReading>> GetAlarmStatusServices()
        {
            var readings = await _dbService.GetAll<AlarmStatusServiceReading>("SELECT * FROM public."Alarm_Status" ORDER BY id ASC ", new { });
            return readings;
        }
```

**The Relation(Table) name is Alarm_Status.**
But how can I mention it with double quotes like mentioned above.
it gives syntax error if I write like above mentioned code.

[image: 00 1]

And if I mentioned without  double quotes it gives me  relation does not exist.

how should I mention my query then .

ASP.net API. and query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't use double-quotes in a literal `string` like that because they denote the end of the `string`. Just like every other special character, double-quotes get escaped:

```cs
"SELECT * FROM public.\"Alarm_Status\" ORDER BY id ASC "
```

Alternatively, you can use a verbatim `string` literal, in which case the escape character is interpreted as a literal character, and then you escape double-quotes exactly as you do in VB:

```cs
@"SELECT * FROM public.""Alarm_Status"" ORDER BY id ASC "
```